# Removing Child Elements from Symbol

Tags: javascript, symbols, children, adobe-edge

I'm trying to implement a History with Adobe Edge Animate and somewhere in a trigger I have to update it. What I'm trying to do is deleting all previous symbols and rewrite them with the updated history content.

This is how I'm creating child symbols:

```
// Creating child symbols

$.each( h.reverse(), function(index, item){
    var itemRenderer = sym.createChildSymbol("ItemRenderer", "HistoryContainer");
    itemRenderer.$("ItemText").text(item);
});
```

Then I try to get all of the child symbols in order to delete them:

```
// Delete all child symbols

var cs = sym.$("HistoryContainer").getChildSymbols();
```

And I get:

```
Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = timeline
```

How am I able to get the list of childSymbols and update the HistoryContainer?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
sym.$("HistoryContainer").getChildSymbols();
```

with:

```
sym.getSymbol("HistoryContainer").getChildSymbols();
```

With your code you are getting the div element (as a jQuery element). In order to have the getChildSymbol method you need to get the AdobeEdge symbol.

Comment: I'm getting an empty array when I call  (sym.getSymbol("HistoryContainer").getChildSymbols()) even after creating all the "ItemRenderer" child symbols of "HistoryContainer".. How am I supposed to delete all of the children?